# On Click of navigation bar button, how to call method defined in UIview

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm newbie in iPhone development. I have a navigation bar button. On click of navigation bar button I want to make to call method of UIView. Is it Possible?

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible. Just set target and action for that bar button and you're done. Or if that method is some outside view (or class) you may call self targeted method inside that view can call outsided view (or class) method.

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tap Me"
 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self 
action:@selector(callOutsideViewMethod)];

- (void)callOutsideViewMethod {
    someView *obj = [someView new];
    [obj someMethodOfThatView];
}
```

I assume you're in ARC environment.